# Jquery droppable with ondrop callback associated to draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

There is one onDrop function associated with the droppable. I have created an tree where i can drag and drop nodes to change their position in the tree.
In a page where I have a list whith elements I want to associate to node by dragging on it.
If I redeclare a new ondrop the one corresponding to the node stopped to work.
What I would like to do is associate the onDrop function with the draggable to add new behaviour depending  on what type of element is dragged.

Comment: Welcome!  Please press [edit] to add some code to the answer.  Also, consider posting a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), which allows people to try your current code interactively.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right (hard to distinguish your aim) you want to have two different functions in drop event.

You can do define each drop event in a namespace so event handler don't get overridden:

```
$('.droppable').on('drop.FirstFunction', function (event, ui) {
     firstFunction();
});

$('.droppable').on('drop.SecondFunction', function (event, ui) {
     secondFunction();
});
```